# recommendations map server open source

Tags: geoserver, software-recommendations

I need to install a server Gis open source

I have to change for economic issues Arcgis server

you could support me with recommendations for servers, open sorces docuemntacion of instalcion

I would like to have geoprocessing services 
Geocoding services 
Network analysis services 
Service Manager workflow

Comment: you are already tagging your question with the good answer

Comment: there is some possibilities: mapserver, geoserver, geodjango are well-known and you'll find plenty documention on internet on those products

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source software and approaches for your question but I suggest options:

GeoServer (www.geoserver.org) - Webmapping server developed in Java by OpenGeo. You can find lots of documentation online (look for the tutorials in the OpenGeo site). GeoServer has a very friendly admin interface so you can install and start publishing your geo data very quickly.

MapServer (www.mapserver.org) - Very traditional webmapping server! You will find many products developed over MapServer. There is lots of documentation online.

Others options: MapProxy/Mapnik, MapBox, CartoDB, etc. MapBox and CartoDB are more cloud solutions but it can useful (depends on your project requirements).